# NavigationBar and TabBar background colors are always grey

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

My TabBar and navigationBar are always grey, tried all StackOverflow solutions I found, but none works. They always stay grey. 
This is my `AppDelegate` code, `MenuViewController` is a `TabBarViewController`.

```
self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
        
        let menuVC = MenuViewController()
        let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: menuVC)
        
        navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = .white
        navigationController.navigationBar.barTintColor = .red
        
        window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
        window?.rootViewController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: MainViewController())
        window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this part of your code:

```
window?.rootViewController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: MainViewController())
```

You're setting the rootViewController to a different instance of `UINavigationController` that has an instance of `MainViewController` as rootViewController.

If you want to present your styled navigation controller with an instance of `MenuViewController` you should set it as the windows root view controller:

```
let menuVC = MenuViewController()
let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: menuVC)
        
navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = .white
navigationController.navigationBar.barTintColor = .red
        
window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
window?.rootViewController = navigationController
window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```